# Imported 3D bodies in Altium are not deleted

Tags: altium, 3d

I added a 3D body to the PCB document from outside. (i.e. these 3D bodies were not included in the PCB documentation as components from the schematic). However, when I try to delete it, it does not select and delete, I can only change the location of the body. Does anyone know the solution? I tried deleting it with version 2021; version 2023 still has the same problem. Does anyone have this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the selection section, only select "components" is marked, the problem is solved.

Comment: This link will take you, with a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: [https://forum.live.altium.com/](https://forum.live.altium.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution, hope it helps other people:

[image]

[image]

1. Right-click the imported 3D body to PCB doc,
2. Click "Find similar objects,"
3. Click "apply",then click "ok", then left-click 3D bodies ,
4. 3D bodies are selected now, press "delete" and done.